# Accessing a named range inside a Worksheet_SelectionChange sub routine

Tags: excel, vba

I have practically no background in VBA and little understanding of its overall structure, but need to make additions/modifications to an existing spreadsheet to accomplish some objectives. This spreadsheet is huge with hundreds of named ranges, and dozens of VBA functions and calculations.

For now, all I am trying to do is:

1. Create a drop-down (data validation type) on sheet 1 - DONE
2. Based on the selection, copy one of many named ranges stored in sheet 2, to a location (say A1) on sheet 3.

To achieve step 2, I started a Worksheet_SelectionChange sub routine and the code is below. Assume two drop-down choices = ABC & XYZ. Assume the two corresponding named ranges to be ABC_data & XYZ_data. These two named ranges are of Workbook scope. They are to be copied to a sheet labeled SheetC.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim PD As String, transferRange As Range
PD = Target.Value
Select Case PD
    Case "ABC"
        transferRange = ABC_data
    Case "XYZ"
        transferRange = XYZ_data '<~ error here, assuming "XYZ" selection
End Select
Range(transferRange).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetC").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Please help me understand what is wrong with this. When I make a selection and debug this sub routine, I get a "Object variable or With block variable not set" error at the `transferRange = XYZ_data` line assuming XYZ selection. It looks like I am not able to access the named ranges within this sub routine. What steps should I take?

Please bear with my patchwork knowledge of what I am doing.

Comment: I meant the error is at the line: transferRange = XYZ_data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a start, `Range` variables must be assigned with the `Set` keyword like this: `Set transferRange = ABC_data` or `Set transferRange = XYZ_data`

Comment: Thanks. There is progress already. Adding Set removed the first error, and instead gave me an "object required" error. After this, I changed the line to:    Set transferRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetB").Range("XYZ_data"). The second error then went away. Now, I am left with an error on the last line where I attempt to copy over the named range. I see the following message: Method "Range" of object "_Worksheet" failed.

Comment: Hmm... can't test this at the moment, but from the looks of it `transferRange` is already a `Range` object, so I don't think you need to wrap it with `Range()`. Do you get the same error with `transferRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetC").Range("A1")`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Note the I added the **Destination:=** bit to hopefully fix your final error:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim PD As String, transferRange As Range
PD = Target.Value
Select Case PD
    Case "ABC"
        Set transferRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetB").Range("ABC_data")
    Case "XYZ"
        Set transferRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetB").Range("XYZ_data")
End Select
Range(transferRange).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetC").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this, but still got the "Method Range..." error. It seems after looking around that it is better to explicitly define the source worksheet, etc, so I changed the last line to:    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetB").Range(transferRange).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetC").Range("A1"). Now, I have a "application-defined or object-defined error"!

Comment: I presume you've tested dan's last suggestion?

Comment: No, I hadn't yet tried it, but I can now report that it does work. Thanks.